# Newlines not appearing as expected in vCard created in php

Tags: php, apache, newline, vcf-vcard

I have the following code that I use to generate a vCard (note that variables are declared earlier)

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:<?php echo $person["last"]; ?>;<?php echo $person["first"];?>;;;
FN:<?php echo $person["first"];?> <?php echo $person["last"]; ?>
ORG:<?php echo str_replace(",",'\,',Site::$NAME);?>
TITLE:CPA
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-<?php echo Site::$PHONE; ?>
TEL;TYPE=work,fax;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-<?php echo Site::$FAX; ?>
ADR;TYPE=work;LABEl="<?php echo Site::$ADDRESS . '\n' . Site::$LINE_TWO . '\n' . Site::$CITY . '\,' . Site::$STATE . " " . Site::$ZIP; ?>":;<?php echo Site::$LINE_TWO; ?>;<?php echo Site::$ADDRESS; ?>;<?php echo Site::$CITY; ?>;<?php echo Site::$STATE; ?>;<?php echo Site::$ZIP; ?>;United States of America
EMAIL:<?php echo $person["email"]; ?>
END:VCARD
```

But the problem is that I do not get new lines where I expect.  Example output:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:LAST;FIRST;;;
FN:FIRST LASTORG:ORGANIZATIONTITLE:TITLE
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:PHONE_NUMBERTEL;TYPE=work,fax;VALUE=uri:PHONE_NUMBERADR;TYPE=work;LABEl="ADDRESS":;ADDRESS
EMAIL:EMAILEND:VCARD
```

For what ever reason some of the newlines are there, and some of them are never outputted.  Is there a reason why this is happening, and is there a way to fix it?

---

**Edit**: I set the following headers prior to any output:

```
header("Content-Type: text/vcard");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $person["first"] . " " . $person["last"] . ".vcf" . '"');
```

Comment: Have you tried adding in a Carriage Return? Certain situations require CRLF (Carriage Return, Line Feed [`\r\n`]) instead of just a straight Line Feed (New Line) character.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I am a little confused.  I am just using the return button in the php file itself, so I am not actually using "\n" directly.  Why would it be working on the first few lines, but not the rest?

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the wrong part. That is very strange indeed. It's possible it's rendering as HTML, which means newlines aren't actually rendered as newlines, but that doesn't explain why some of them have newlines while others do not. My only other thoughts would be encoding error of some sort, or strange output from the PHP script itself. Perhaps `echo`ing out the vcard, and explicitly declaring newlines would solve the problem. You could concatenate any needed variables in. Still, it doesn't explain why the newline works so intermittently.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I will edit the question to show the lines that indicate that the response should be a vCard

Comment: You might consider [using a library for this](https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that php removes newlines after the php closing tag `?>`.
There are several ways to work around this.

- you could for example append a blank space after the closing tag
- or add an additional newline after the closing tag
- or you could `echo` the whole vcard data using `\n` as newlines, instead of opening and closing php everytime

Comment: Wow.  After googling I'm surprised I never found this.  This is also good to know for the future. Thank you.